# Python traceback for coroutine

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

Let's say I have the following code:

```
from types import coroutine

@coroutine
def stop():
    yield 1

async def test2():
    await stop()

async def test1():
    await test2()
    await test2() # Here
    await test2()

coro = test1()
coro.send(None)
coro.send(None)
```

How can I get traceback (traceback object) for current coroutine state, i.e. line marked with comment, without artificially throwing unneeded exception?

Answer (score 2):

Use of `traceback.print_stack()` will give you the exact same traceback as thrown exception:

```
async def test1():
    await test2()

    traceback.print_stack()
    # raise Exception()

    await test2() # Here
    await test2()
```

You can use [traceback.extract_stack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack) if you want to recieve object instead of printing.

---

Note however that you're doing something strange. `asyncio` coroutines is not supposed to be run use it's generator's nature functions like `.send()`.

In `asyncio` you await for coroutines and run top level coroutine using event loop. Please see how it's done in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).

I write another small example that shows how to print start inside inner coroutine when you use `asyncio` regular way:

```
import asyncio
import traceback


async def test3():
    traceback.print_stack()


async def test2():
    await test3()


async def test1():
    await test2()


asyncio.run(test1())
```

You'll see:

```
  File "C:\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    asyncio.run(test1())

  # inner event loop stack here

  File "C:\main.py", line 21, in test1
    await test2()
  File "C:\main.py", line 17, in test2
    await test3()
  File "C:\main.py", line 13, in test3
    traceback.print_stack()
```